# GitHub: Make a private repository partially public

Tags: git, github, repository

I have built a project with `html + css + javascript` on GitHub for a half year. It has been in a private repository, there is only one branch.

Now I want to make this repository **partially** public, such that:

1. Users can use the `issues` feature to ask questions or write requirements, I could respond to them, we could have discussion.
2. Actually, users don't need to see the code. But as we are on GitHub, I may want to make a small part of files public.
3. I don't want to lose the commit history.

Could anyone tell me what are the steps (and commands ideally) I should follow?

Do I have to re-organize my folders, for example, make a public folder and a private folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to understand is the GitHub permissions model.  To submit issues, etc. requires *some* level of permission to a repo.  Read should be sufficient.

But read *does* also mean "able to see all code and history".  And able to see even means able to copy and fork, even though you control what can be written back to your repo.  And there is no access level lower than "read (all the code)".

So if you want to keep your code to yourself, then creating some sort of project page apart from github, and tapping into a dedicated issue tracking system there, may just make more sense for what you're trying to do.

If you do decide that *some* code should be public, then you'd have to have two repos.  The repo with the public code could be made read only, or read/write if that better meets your needs for that subset of the code.  Either way it could then host issue discussions, etc.

Splitting a subset of code into a public repo isn't *too* hard, though it's harder if you want the public repo to have full history as well.  You'll want to avoid creating two divergent histories of the public code, so you'll probably have to remove the public code from the private repo.  (It can be re-introduced as a submodule - a link to the public repo - but in the simplest case that does mean you'll want to organize the public code under a single directory.)

If only current versions need to be made public, then it's straightforward.  You init the new repo, move the files from one to the other, create the submodule link if you want it.

If you want to publish history of the published files, then you'd have to do something like `git filter-branch` to create the public repo from (a clone of) the original repo.  The exact procedure depends on the exact requirements, but generally you might use either (a) a `subdirectory-filter` to publish only the contents of one directory (to the root of the new repo) - but it sounds like your code isn't arranged to make that easy; or (b) an `index-filter` to remove the files you want to keep private (while keeping the existing directory structure for the files that remain); or (c) a `tree-filter` and as complex a script as you like to move, remove, or add files around, transforming an "original repo" version into a corresponding "public repo" version.

If you do split the history, you'll probably still want to keep the history of the public files in the original repo simply because linking the repos' histories is rather difficult.  It's not a huge practical limitation most of the time, unless the size of the history is considerable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really like "issues" of Github as "issue tracking system". Do you think if it is acceptable to create a Github repository with some project pages to mostly use its "issues" feature?

Comment: I guess I don't know what would make it "acceptable" or otherwise. I don't recall seeing it done, probably because there exist sites that specifically focus on issue management without integrated source control; but I don't know why you couldn't, if it's really what you want to do

Answer (score 3):

You will definitely need two repositories. But you can create a public part automatically.

For example, you can use [git-exporter](https://github.com/open-condo-software/gitexporter). It allows you to define file paths available in a public repository. This utility creates a new git repository based on an existing one with a similar commit history. Only allowed files will be included in the commit contents.

Example:

Create `config.json`:

```
{
    "forceReCreateRepo": true,
    "targetRepoPath": "my-open-source-repo",
    "sourceRepoPath": ".",
    "allowedPaths": ["build/*"],
    "ignoredPaths": ["src/*"]
}
```

Then run command `npx gitexporter config.json`.

Thus, a new repository `my-open-source-repo` will be created that includes only certain files while preserving the entire commit history.

Then you can push `my-open-source-repo` and use it as Open Source.

Like so:

```
cd my-open-source-repo
git remote set-url origin new.github.com/username/open-source-repo-name
git push origin master
```

You can also create a CI script that will update your public `my-open-source-repo` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You even need two separate repositories. Either the code is public or not. you cannot make just a part of the files public. Unless you package those files up as an archive and provide them in the downloads section of the repo. But if you want to make them available as repository, you need to split your repository in two halves, e. g. with `git filter-tree` and a `--subtree-filter`.

Comment: Sorry, I just found [this post](http://alexgaudio.com/2011/07/24/sharing-part-your-repo-github.html), is it a different approach than yours?

Comment: From a quick skimming it is a different approach (while the update at the top says exactly what I said) that does not apply for you. They have the private repo not on GitHub but somewhere else or purley local. They prepare a branch that contains only the files to be shared and push only that branch to the GitHub repository. This also is an approach that involves two separate repositories, one with the public stuff, one with the private and public stuff, having a separate branch for the public stuff that is the only one pushed to the public remote. Pretty cumbersome and fragile I'd say.